# I know this is all the possible permutation map to the number of students, but how do I set it up?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose a lazy professor collects a quiz from each student in a class, then shuffles the papers and redistributes them randomly to the class for grading. How likely is it that no one receives his or her own quiz to grade?

How do I set it up?

Comment: Relevant keyword: *derangement*. See e.g. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399500/why-is-the-derangement-probability-so-close-to-frac1e) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022673/permutation-without-fixed-points/2023219#2023219).

Answer (score 0):

We can get by inclusion exclusion that $!n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(-1) ^n \binom{n}{i}(n-i)!=n!\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{i!}$.

So $\frac{!n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{i!}$. There is no closed formula for this, however if you look at the taylor series for $e^x$ it is clear that it approaches $e^{-1}$ when $n$ goes to infinity.